# How to create an executable (preferably a .exe and not command line) out of a Coded UI Test?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to create an executable out of a Coded UI Test which opens a browser and performs a set of operations. I would prefer a simple .exe file instead of using a batch file or using MS Test Agent, to be able to run it across computers without issues. Any other way of executing the Coded UI Test with a simple click, without the use of Visual Studio is welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create a .exe file from `CodedUi Project` but you can use another Project for that.

**Step 1**

Create your `CodedUi Project`.  Use the `CodedUi Test Builder` to create your `TestMethod(s)` that executes the actions you want.

**Step 2**

Create another Project that has a reference to your `CodedUi Test Project`and calls your recorded `Test Methods`. If you just need to run only one method then create a simple `Console Application`. If you need something more complicated (e.g. choose the `CodedUI Test Method` to run) a `Windows Form Application` would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

I know that is late, anyway this can serve to others more.

You can delegate this work to MSTest, you can do a .bat or make a console application that executes the next:

```
set MSTestEXE=%PROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe
"%MSTestEXE%" /testcontainer:CodedUITest\bin\Debug\CodedUITest.dll
```

**CodedUITest.dll** is the dll that generates Visual Studio.

**MsTest** will execute all tests showing you the results on the CMD and even will generate the **TestResult.trx** file.